# Is removing the disks from readynas duo v1 and reconnecting them after performing a factory reset likely to cause data loss?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

As mentioned in the topic, ı want to remove disks then perform factory reset to clear mistaken configuration and lastly insert the disks back. Is there any possible data loss chance in this operation?
Thanks in advance